# Dominant set of a Graph - Convert to Conjunctive Normal Form

Tags: logic, graph-theory, satisfiability, conjunctive-normal-form

I am supposed to convert this problem to a Satisfiability Problem in Conjunctive Normal Form, but I have no idea how.

The Problem:
Determine, if there exists any dominant set for a Graph $G$ containing at most $n/4$ vertices. ($n = $ total number of vertices in $G$

Could you please help me or at least give me a hint or explain how to do it, because I have really no idea :(

Comment: What is a dominant set of a graph? What have you tried so far? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: a dominating set for a graph $G = (V, E)$ is a subset $D$ of $V$ such that every vertex not in $D$ is adjacent to at least one member of $D$

Comment: I tried converting the graph into CNF using a list of adjacent vertices of each vertex, but I just don't know how to do it so that the SAT solver would determine if there exists such a set